# Postgresql - Generate a percentage from value where 100% is a specific value and an average over days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in my table with generated values. I want to generate a percent complete column

336 is 100% complete.

what is the percent complete.

end result should be new column in result, complete

> Sample Data :

```
ID| Value 

1 | 168

2 | 84

3 | 67.2
```

> result

```
ID | Value | complete

1 | 168 | 50%

2 | 84  | 25%

3 | 67.2| 20%
```

that is the percent of 336

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really hep.

Answer (score 2):

This should return what you need:

```
Select ID, Value, ((Value/336) * 100) as complete
From sample_data_table
```